# Choosing a value from a sorted array in C

Tags: arrays, c

I'm new to C and I've got a question about arrays.

I need to display an array, containing numbers, easy enough. Then, the troubling part, the user is supposed to enter a value, which represents the ranking of the values in the array, think of it like a list of prices, the lower the entered number, the smaller the printed out number is, and I've got no clue how to do it.

I've tried a bubble sort, which sorts all the numbers in the array, but then what?

For example, the array is `10, 1000, 50` if the user enters 1, they would get 10, the smallest, if they enter 3, they'd get 1000.

Here is the code I stole straight from some website, all this does is arrange the array in a bubble sort

```
#include <stdio.h>
 
void swap(int *xp, int *yp)
{
    int temp = *xp;
    *xp = *yp;
    *yp = temp;
}
 
// A function to implement bubble sort
void bubbleSort(int arr[], int n)
{
   int i, j;
   for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++)     
 
       // Last i elements are already in place  
       for (j = 0; j < n-i-1; j++)
           if (arr[j] > arr[j+1])
              swap(&arr[j], &arr[j+1]);
}
 
/* Function to print an array */
void printArray(int arr[], int size)
{
    int i;
    for (i=0; i < size; i++)
        printf("%d ", arr[i]);
    printf("\n");
}
 
// Driver program to test above functions
int main()
{
    int arr[] = {25000, 10000, 25000, 90000, 90000, 25000, 25000, 10000, 10000, 25000};
    int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    bubbleSort(arr, n);
    printf("Sorted array: \n");
    printArray(arr, n);
    return 0;
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Were you actually required to write your own sorting code or why did you go for one of the least efficient ways of sorting an array? Also what exactly is the problem with accessing the element that the user requests?

Comment: If `arr` is sorted and the user enters that he/she wants number `r` (from 1 and up) then `arr[r - 1]` should give you the number you want.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Hmm. If displaying all values of an array is _"easy enough"_, then displaying the n'th element of the array shouldn't be a problem for you...

Comment: There's a really optimized function for that in `stdlib.h` called `qsort`; you really don't need to do anything else save in rare cases.

Comment: sorry for the confusion, basically theres several arrays, each with values in them, the task is to write a function that can look at the arrays, and choose for example the smallest number in that array, if the value is 3, it'll return the third smallest number in the array, etc thanks for the attention